# Archive pages with full month names?

Tags: templating, localization, datetime

I've got News Archive pages that display all entries posted in a certain month/year. For example June 2016 shows all entries created in June of 2016!

I'm fetching the entries based on `craft.request.segment` (as the URL ends in /june/2016 etc). This works great for all English months, but when my URL says /juni/2016 (the German month name) it can't find any entries??

```
{% set month = craft.request.segment(2) %}
{% set year = craft.request.segment(3) %}
```

It's defintely a translation thing. Anyone know how `craft.request.segment` can work with locales (German and simplified Chinese) too?

Comment: Does your URI structure change for German so that it's in a different segment?  i.e. site.com/de/archives/juni/2016 vs. site.com/archives/june/2016?

Comment: Sorry, I was just about to answer this question myself. See #help channel in Slack! ;-)

Comment: lol - of course.  i'd expect nothing less from you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig’s `date` filter is aware of the current Craft locale, so you should be able to create a DateTime after composing a string that the filter accepts (see PHP [`strtotime` function](http://www.php.net/en/strtotime) docs, which the filter uses behind the scenes).

```
{% set day = 1 %}
{% set month = 'juni' %}
{% set year = 2016 %}

{% set dateString = [day, month, year]|join(' ') %}
{% set date = dateString|date %}

{{ date }}
```